# How to include a conditional statement within this array?

Tags: php

Current code:

```
$columns = array(
    array('db' => 'code', 'dt' => 0),
    array('db' => 'img', 'dt' => 1),
    array('db' => 'name', 'dt' => 2),
    array('db' => 'short_description', 'dt' => 3),
);
```

What I would like to create (I know this code is invalid, I need advice on how to achieve what I am going for):

```
$i=0;
$code=$_POST['code'];
$img=$_POST['img'];
$name=$_POST['name'];
$short_description=$_POST['short_description'];


$columns = array(
    if($code){
    array('db' => 'code', 'dt' => $i),
    i++;
    }else if($img){
    array('db' => 'img', 'dt' => $i),
    i++;
    }else if($name){
    array('db' => 'name', 'dt' => $i),
    i++;
    }else if($short_description){
    array('db' => 'short_description', 'dt' => $i),
    }
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like this

```
if(!empty($code))
$columns[] =  array('db' => 'code', 'dt' => $i++);
else if(!empty($img))
$columns[] =  array('db' => 'img', 'dt' => $i++);
else if(!empty($name))
$columns[] =  array('db' => 'name', 'dt' => $i++);
else if(!empty($short_description))
$columns[] =  array('db' => 'short_description', 'dt' => $i++);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php).

```
$columns = array(
    array('db' => 'code', 'dt' => 0),
    array('db' => 'img', 'dt' => 1),
    array('db' => 'name', 'dt' => 2),
    array('db' => 'short_description', 'dt' => 3),
);

if ({your condition}) {
    $columns = array_merge($columns, array(array('db' => 'short_description', 'dt' => 3)));
}
```